# Why doesn’t my Laravel project show the .env file on a Mac?

Tags: laravel-5

Why doesn’t my Laravel project show the .env file on a Mac?

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: You're probably not showing hidden files, e.g. files with names that start with a dot

Comment: How to show it sir?

Comment: Search on google for "how to see hidden files in X" where X is the name of the program you're using

Comment: Ohh, thank you sir

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You're not showing hidden files

- Open Terminal found in Finder > Applications > Utilities
- In Terminal, paste the following: `defaults write com.apple.finder  AppleShowAllFiles YES`
- Press return
- Hold the ‘Option/alt’ key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock
  and click Relaunch.

This will show all hidden files
[Here's how to show them on mac](https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

Answer (score 32):

If you would like to see hidden file in Finder just press `CMD + SHIFT + .`

Answer (score 1):

In mac > open the folder where you want to show the hidden file.
than just press:

```
cmd + shift+ .
```

It must work.